# Android Studio's Window is not rendered/blank

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

How to fix this blank window?

The worst

[image: Window 3]

After some mouse click

[image: Window 1]

How the window should look like

[image: window 2]

I did clean install but the problem still happen.

Comment: Q: How do I show options in Android Studio Device Chooser?  A: Create some AVDs?  Plug in a handset?  Use a 3rd party emulator like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)?

Comment: @paulsm4 If you plug a device it will show in the "Choose running device" or you can choose "Lauch Emulator" to run android emulator(AVD). I dont know about geny.

Comment: Any running Genymotion (not "Geny") emulator shows up as a "running device" you can choose.  *THAT'S THE ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION!*  That's the answer I gave you; that's the answer suku gave you a few moments ago.  *JUST ADD ONE OR MORE DEVICES*!

Comment: @paulsm4 Aw sorry. My problem is not that. My problem is the blank window which you can see on the screenshoot, some area in the window is black. The window show completely blank at first but if i touch some button it not blank anymore but not with non touchable element(as you can see above). Here is how the window should look like https://www.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/4.png

Comment: You should check the Android Studio log (`Help | Show log`) for exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing the window makes the text appear again

Comment: My problem is the blank window which you can see on the screenshoot, some area in the window is black. The window show completely blank at first but if i touch some button it not blank anymore but not with non touchable element(as you can see above)
Here is the window should looklike https://www.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/4.png

Comment: I also have Intellij Installed on my Laptop but it completely normal, only this android studio. I did reinstall the AS, Invalidate Cache/restart, delete the settings but still not solve the problem.

Comment: try resizing the window. Even I am not able to see options for somethings and resizing the window helps

Comment: Thanks it solve the problem. But still i have to manually resize them to fix it.

Comment: I don't know why it's caused. But if it solves the problem then mark my answer as correct